# return parameters from command line program

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass a String via Command Line in java, but it returns only the first value i.e. `args[0]`

Below is what I've done

```
public class CommandLine
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        i = args[0].length(); //throws error here if args.length();
        System.out.println(i); //checking length, return with args[0] only
         while(i>0)
        {
            System.out.println(args[0]);
            i++;
        } 
    }
}
```

> What should I do to improve this and make it working?

Comment: Well, your loop specifically says `args[0]`, so I guess it is doing what you told it to. But `while(i > 0)` and `i++` that doesn't sound right...

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that, I've added that part of the code just because `args.length();` was making me sound stupid and didn't worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few things to be addressed

1. In your logic command line arugment length is taken in wrong way.
2. Loop condition is not apt for your requirement, moreover It is an infinite loop or never ending loop which reduces the performace of the code.Should never use infinite loops in the code.

3.you are printing the same index ie.. args[0] every time inside loop.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i=0;
        int len = args.length;   //use length only in this case;
        System.out.println(len); // this will return it properly now
        while(i<len)
        {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
            i++;
        } 
    }
```